# Comparing only initial fraction of number String in Java

Tags: java, string, split

I have 2 number strings :

```
String a = "9.8.0.0.10"

String b = "10.0.0.0.11"
```

I want to compare initial part(Initial 2 parts) of String only like `if(9.8 > 10.0)`
This is what i am doing :

```
String[] aPart = a.split("\\.",3)

String[] bPart = b.split("\\.",3)

String resultA = new StringBuilder(aPart[0]).append(".").append(aPart[1]).toString();

String resultB = new StringBuilder(bPart[0]).append(".").append(bPart[1]).toString()
```

then

```
if(Double.parseDouble(resultA) > Double.parseDouble(resultB)
```

Is there any better way i can compare 9.8 and 10.0 rather than doing splitting followed by concat and then parsing which is worse practice here...

Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't it be \\. instead of \. ?

Comment: yes..sorry it was typo

Comment: Can first number be greather than 99, or 999 ?

Comment: No..it will max go till 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first number can't be greater than 20, you can use a simple regex :

```
String a = "9.8.0.0.10";
String b = "10.0.0.0.11";
String convertRegexp = "(^[0-9]{1,2}\\.[0-9]+)\\..*";        

double aAsDouble = Double.parseDouble(a.replaceAll(convertRegexp, "$1"));
double bAsDouble = Double.parseDouble(b.replaceAll(convertRegexp, "$1"));

if(aAsDouble > bAsDouble)
```

Comment: Perfect ..This is what i wanted. Thank you !!